# Spring Security returning guest instead of UserDetails for Authentication.getPrincipal()

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm trying to implement spring security 3.1.0.M1 and I'm unable to get my application to set the Authentication.getPrincipal to my custom UserDetails implementation.  It always returns a principal of "guest" when I try to get the logged in user.  See getLoggedInUser method below.

In Users.java (UserDetails impl) the getAuthorities method never gets called and maybe that's why the user_role doesn't get assigned.

to Maybe I've misconfigured something...I've attached an outline of my implementation hoping someone can spot my error. Thanks for the assistance!

```
public static Users getLoggedInUser() {
    Users user = null;
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (auth != null && auth.isAuthenticated()) {
        Object principal = auth.getPrincipal();
        if (principal instanceof Users) {
            user = (Users) principal;
        }
    }
    return user;
}
```

security context file(removed the xml and schema definitions):

```
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled">
</global-method-security>
<http security="none" pattern="/services/rest-api/1.0/**" />
<http security="none" pattern="/preregistered/**" />
<http access-denied-page="/auth/denied.html">
    <intercept-url
        pattern="/**/*.xhtml"
        access="ROLE_NONE_GETS_ACCESS" />
    <intercept-url
        pattern="/auth/**"
        access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url
        pattern="/auth/*"
        access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
     <intercept-url
        pattern="/**"
        access="ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login
        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check.html"
        login-page="/auth/login.html"
        default-target-url="/registered/home.html"
        authentication-failure-url="/auth/login.html?_dc=45" />
    <logout logout-url="/auth/logout.html"
            logout-success-url="/" />
    <anonymous username="guest" granted-authority="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
    <remember-me user-service-ref="userManager" key="valid key here"/>
</http>
<!-- Configure the authentication provider -->
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userManager">
            <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

UserDetails Implementation (Users.java):

```
public class Users implements Serializable, UserDetails {
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
     List<GrantedAuthority> auth = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    auth.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_USER"));
    return auth;
}
```

}

user-service-ref="userManager" (UserManagerImpl.java):

```
 public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
    Users user = null;
    try {
        user = userDAO.findByUsername(username);
    } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid login", ex);
    }
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found.");
    }
    return user;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you not getting compilation error on this line: `auth.add("ROLE_USER");`?

I think it should be : `auth.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));`

Comment: @Ritesh, I tried to add the "ROLE_USER" constant to try to make it more clear but I think it had the opposite effect.  In my version I actually use public static final Authority AUTHORITY_USER = new Authority("ROLE_USER"); List<GrantedAuthority> auth = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            auth.add(Authority.AUTHORITY_USER);
            return auth; p

Comment: @Ritesh, thanks for the response, I've added the authority class to the initial question...thanks for the help!

Comment: @colin I am not sure why you created Authority class when SimpleGrantedAuthority class is already there in framework. Also you didn't override toString() method in the class. See the javadoc of GrantedAuthority interface. It says: "A GrantedAuthority must either represent itself as a String or be specifically supported by an AccessDecisionManager."

Comment: @Ritesh, I don't see the SimpleGrantedAuthority class in the spring-security-core-3.1.0.M1.jar but I did notice the GrantedAuthorityImpl which I used instead of the Authority.class I had. I've updated my Users.java getAuthorites method above to use this new class but it still never gets called by Spring.  Any ideas on why it never gets executed?

Comment: @Ritesh, I created the Authority.java so I could serialze the Users.java object.  I can't do that when I use the GrantedAuthorityImpl as I get an exception, just fyi.

Comment: @Ritesh, I now see that I'm getting an BadCredentialsException.  The credentials entered by the user match exactly whats in the database and I don't see the Spring code that compares the j_password value against that of the users.getPassword from the db, any ideas?

Comment: @colin DaoAuthenticationProvider calls UserDetailsService implementation (userManager in your case) to retrieve and validate user information. After getting user information, it calls passwordEncoder to validate password. The passwordEncoder compares the j_password value against that of the users.getPassword from the db.

Comment: @colin Also, since you are storing password as it is, make sure you are using PlaintextPasswordEncoder with salt as null.